# How could I use window.alert(); but not showing hide elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, alert, show

I use jQuery to hide my navigation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div#c_navi ul li div').hide();
  jQuery('div#c_navi > ul > li > a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
  });
  $('div#c_navi02 ul li ul').hide();
  jQuery('div#c_navi02 > ul > li > a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
  });});
```

But when I use

```
window.alert("success!!");
```

It shows all of my hide elements.

How could I use window.alert(); but not showing hide elements?
Thanks!

Comment: where did you use `window.alert("success!!");`??

Comment: I have form table, and after users add new data, it will show the success diaolog

Comment: This is impossible. Issue should be somewhere else

Comment: DOM manipulation(e.g show/hide etc) inside a javascript code takes effect only after execution of your code. In your case it may be that you are using 'alert' during the same phase. And thus your element will be hidden only after dismissal of alert. If this is the case you may want to put alert inside setTimeout fn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it **after** hiding them:

```
...
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#c_navi ul li div').hide();
    $('div#c_navi02 ul li ul').hide();
    window.alert("success!!");

    jQuery('div#c_navi > ul > li > a').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    });

    jQuery('div#c_navi02 > ul > li > a').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will solve the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div#c_navi ul li div').hide();
  jQuery('div#c_navi > ul > li > a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
  });
  $('div#c_navi02 ul li ul').hide();
  jQuery('div#c_navi02 > ul > li > a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
  });
  window.alert("success!!");
});
```

Comment: It can work, but I have to use other php code inside.
But still thanks!! :)

Comment: like this: `setTimeout(function(){window.alert("<?php echo $_SESSION["msg"]; ?>")}, 100);` Anyway, thanks a lot!!